# Филологическая загадка

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Какое **двойное** утверждение в русском языке иногда обозначает  отрицание?
А может быть, у нас много таких утверждений?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Ага, конечно!..*

Нашёл анекдот на эту тему [тут](http://www.ermak.su/context/fil_anekdoty.htm) (приведён с изменениями из-за отсутствия здравого смысла в варианте по ссылке):

> На филфаке идет лекция по языкознанию. Преподаватель самозабвенно вещает:
>   – Есть языки, в которых два отрицания подряд означают отрицание или утверждение. Есть языки, в которых отрицание и утверждение, поставленные рядом, означают отрицание, а есть языки, в которых та же самая комбинация означает утверждение. Но нет такого языка, в котором двойное утверждение обозначало бы отрицание!
>   Голос студента с задней парты:
>   – Ну да, конечно!

Comment: Точно. Некоторые  филологические анекдоты довольно смешные и позволяют взглянуть со стороны на нашу речь.

Comment: Этот анекдот - действительный случай: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgenbesser